# Can not find the source of a Custom Error Page in .NET MVC5 application

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-mvc-5

I am recently taking over a .NET MVC5 application.

In the `HomeController.cs` under the `ActionResult` method there is the following code;

```
throw new Exception("Test error page");
```

the above line of code trigger an error page under the view director  `error.cshtml`

My question is how the above line of code trigger the error page I looked everywhere and there is nothing that connect that line of code in the controller to the error page. Would someone tell how it works?.

I usually use the following steps to create a custom error page:

1. Edit the web.config with `<customError>` tag.
2. Add `[handleError]` attribute in the Controller.
3. Add an `error.cshmtl` page in the shared directory under view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What triggered this Error.cshtml, is the global HandleErrorAttribute that is added by default in the App_Start\FilterConfig.cs file when creating a new MVC project.

The default contents of this file is:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

Removing this HandleErrorAttribute addition will remove the search for Error.cshtml

Comment: @Tân Nguyễn ... Thank you so  much for your help Tan.